# Will it make a difference if I use non-ASCII chars as ENUM values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I think most people will use alphabet chars (English) as ENUM values in PostgreSQL. What about using Asian chars (Japanese, Chinese, Korean)? Will that make a different on performance or other perspective? Is that recommended or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't make a difference, as these strings are only ever compared for equality, which is independent from the encoding. Under the hood, they are `double precision`.

The more important consideration when using enums is that they are only suitable if the values don't ever change. For example, you cannot remove an enum value.